# Differences in scoring from PMML model on different platforms

Tags: r, hadoop, machine-learning, pmml

I've built a toy Random Forest model in `R` (using the `German Credit` dataset from the `caret` package), exported it in `PMML 4.0` and deployed onto Hadoop, using the `Cascading Pattern` library.

I've run into an issue where `Cascading Pattern` scores the same data differently (in a binary classification problem) than the same model in `R`. Out of 200 observations, 2 are scored differently.

Why is this? Could it be due to a difference in the implementation of Random Forests?

Comment: Fitting random forests involves bootstrapping which is a random process. It's possible to run the same code on the same machine in the same language and get different results based on random chance as far as I understand. Is it always the same 2 observations that are different?

Comment: It is always the same 2. But I would understand the difference if it appeared when I was building/fitting a model. This happens when I'm running an already built model on a test set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `German Credit` dataset represents a classification-type problem. The winning score of a classification-type RF model is simply the class label that was the most frequent among member decision trees.

Suppose you have RF model with 100 decision trees, and 50 decision trees predict "good credit" and another 50 decision trees predict "bad credit". It is possible that `R` and `Cascading Pattern` resolve such tie situations differently - one picks the score that is seen first and the other picks the score that is seen last. You could try re-training your RF model with odd number of member decision trees (ie. use some value that is not divisible by two, such as 99 or 101).

The PMML specification tells to return the score that was seen first. I'm not sure if `Cascading Pattern` pays any attention to such details. You may want to try out an alternative solution called [JPMML-Cascading](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-cascading).

Comment: I used your advice, and grew an odd number of trees. Now there's just one mismatch (0.5%). Still need to get to the bottom of that one.

Comment: Have you tried other PMML scoring engines besides `Cascading Pattern`? I have built RF to PMML converter in the past (in Java) and would be interested in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: That's the next step - trying `jpmml-cascading` and `openscoring`. I just wanted to make sure I've done as much as I could from R's end. Another problem is that `Cascading Pattern` insists on `PMML 4.0` for Random Forests, which means I need to use R's `pmml v1.2.30` instead of the current `pmml 1.4.2` version (with `PMML 4.2`). So maybe the other two libraries support the newest versions, and that solves the problem as well.

Comment: You can use the latest `pmml` package if you want to. Once you have exported the file, simply change the version suffix in the XML namespace declaration from `PMML-4_2` to `PMML-4_0`.

Comment: Change everything in the first line to 4.0? `<PMML version="4.0" xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_0 http://www.dmg.org/v4-0/pmml-4-0.xsd">`

Comment: It works that way, thanks! But there's still that one, same, mismatch. Will have to try other libraries.

Comment: If the problem persists with other libraries, please contact the maintainer of the `JPMML` project (see GitHub contacts). Would be interesting to do an in-depth technical analysis over that matter & blog about the results.

Comment: Tried with `openscoring`, with an odd number of trees, and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Score matching is a big deal. When a model is moved from the scientist's desktop to the production IT deployment environment, the scores need to match. For a classification task, that also includes the probabilities of all target categories. There is sometimes a problem of precision between different implementations/platforms which can result in minimal differences (really minimal). In any case, they also need to be checked.

Obviously, it could also be the case that the model was not represented correctly in PMML ... unlikely with the R PMML Package. The other option is that the model is not deployed correctly. That is, the scoring engine cascading is using is not interpreting the PMML file properly.

PMML itself has a model element called ModelVerification that allows for a PMML file to contain scored data which can then be used for score matching. This is useful but not necessary since you should be able to score an already scored dataset and compared computed with expected results which you are already doing.

For more on model verification and score matching as well as error handling in PMML, check:
https://support.zementis.com/entries/21207918-Verifying-your-model-in-ADAPA-did-it-upload-correctly-

Comment: May I ask, how would you quantify "minimal" difference? I uses the advice by @user1808924 and grown an odd number of tress, and that reduces the mismatch from 1% to 0.5%.